# For non compact operators, is countability of singular values equivalent to countability of eigenvalues?

Tags: operator-theory, spectral-theory, compact-operators, singular-values

Generally speaking, compact operators have countable eigenvalues and countable s-values (or singular values). What about the reverse? If I know that a (non-compact) operator has countable singular values, can I deduce that it also has countable eigenvalues?

Answer (score 2):

No. Consider a separable Hilbert, fix an orthonormal basis, and let $S$ be the unilateral shift. The operator $T=S^*$ has uncountably many eigenvalues, since every $\lambda\in\mathbb C$ with $|\lambda|<1$ is an eigenvalue. But $T^*T=SS^*$ is a projection, so in particular its eigenvalues are $0$ and $1$.

That is, $T$ has uncountably many eigenvalues and two singular values.

Comment: That is very clear! Thanks a lot. I actually found a reference explaining almost exactly what you describe: http://individual.utoronto.ca/jordanbell/notes/unilateral.pdf

Comment: Any idea what happens if the operator is an integral operator? Shift operators are often used to provide counterexamples, but in my own situation the operator I'm interested in is an integral operator (yet it is not compact).

Comment: Sorry, I don't know enough about integral operators (nor do you say what your setup is) to say whether the same can happen or not.